# meteor error on adding materialize package

Tags: meteor, materialize

I just created an empty meteor app and it looks like including [materialize](https://atmospherejs.com/materialize/materialize) package into meteor application by running `meteor add materialize:materialize` produces the following error in browser console when I start the meteor application:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'guid' of undefined(anonymous function) @ materialize.js:2(anonymous function) @ materialize_materialize.js?dc17392a9a3ee90d7260ca5fb3f114186ddbe932:42(anonymous function) @ materialize_materialize.js?dc17392a9a3ee90d7260ca5fb3f114186ddbe932:51
global-imports.js?f3a8210e13a775671b88b311040d18b5595730c1:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Materialize' of undefined(anonymous function) @ global-imports.js?f3a8210e13a775671b88b311040d18b5595730c1:3
template.test-materialize.js?db9efeb690fbdd904fe4b351652e4822e8f5d459:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined(anonymous function) @ template.test-materialize.js?db9efeb690fbdd904fe4b351652e4822e8f5d459:2(anonymous function) @ template.test-materialize.js?db9efeb690fbdd904fe4b351652e4822e8f5d459:18
test-materialize.js?c2e184d448010d8345127ffbaf10ce04b6d355e3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined(anonymous function) @ test-materialize.js?c2e184d448010d8345127ffbaf10ce04b6d355e3:1(anonymous function) @ test-materialize.js?c2e184d448010d8345127ffbaf10ce04b6d355e3:25
```

Comment: Try this package instead: https://github.com/d0minikk/materialize-meteor

Answer (score 16):

This seems to be a new problem with the latest version of the package. Do this to fix the problem:

```
meteor remove materialize:materialize
meteor add materialize:materialize@=0.97.0
```

And see here for the GitHub issue: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2043

Comment: This worked for me, I installed 0.97.7 and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest version of materialize via CDN in your app.js file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I am following this method ( atleast till the package is fixed ),& should work just fine for you needs.

Comment: If the question is about installing packages, it does not make sense to insert references through external links