# Meteor Issue after last update (materialize:materialize and fourseven:scss)

Tags: meteor, sass, materialize

I had no errors before the last update about an hour ago. The update I made had the following changes:

```
Changes to your project's package version selections from updating package versions:

babel-runtime            upgraded from 0.1.12 to 0.1.13
fourseven:scss           upgraded from 3.10.0 to 3.10.1
materialize:materialize  upgraded from 0.97.7 to 0.97.8
```

the current version of meteor is `1.4.2`

after the update I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Scss compiler error: Undefined variable: "$medium-and-down"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Materialize' of undefined
ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
```

this was after updating to materialize version 0.97.8

even after downgrading to version 0.97.7, I still get the same error.

Any help is appreciated. I have created this issue [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3863).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just resolved the same issue with this:

```
meteor remove materialize:materialize
meteor add materialize:materialize@=0.97.0
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609708/3863932

Comment: Thanks, I did `meteor add materialize:materialize@0.97.0` instead of `meteor add materialize:materialize@=0.97.0`. The equals made all the difference!

Comment: tip: try to add version 0.97.7 as it has many many improvements since 0.97.0

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the problem though... 
the problem is that he upgraded materialize from 0.97.7 to 0.97.8 and it broke.
the answer posited is to revert back to 0.97.0 or 0.97.7; which is back to where he was originally.

Answer (score 0):

- rm -rf node_modules
- npm install